# How should I handle firebase login errors?

Tags: javascript, firebase, twitter

I have code like this:

```
var auth = firebase.auth()
var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    if (result) {
        var user = result.user;
        //init(user);
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    term.error(error.message).resume();
    term.error('try again');
});
```

and I've just get error but I've got this as error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"Malformed response cannot be parsed"}],"code":400,"message":"Malformed response cannot be parsed"}}
try again
```

Does it mean that to get the message I need to call:

```
error.message.message
```

and error object is `error.message.error`?

Or is the `error.message` string of a json from twitter?

I can't find this information in documentation and I can't look at developer tools because when I've run the code again I didn't get the same error, it was some temporary glitch.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue using Twitter Oauth, namely `Malformed response cannot be parsed` message.

The fix was for me to sign out of my Twitter account that has the oauth app then sign back in. That seems to be the fix for me.